# wait() gets Interupted system call

Tags: c

I thought that wait() fuction will wait until the proces has done, however it receives a signal -1. Does anyone know the reason of the problem? May be the problem is my shared memory? So I tried to make a debugging, and in the debbuging mode there is no problem like when I run my code in normal mode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define PROCESSES 3

struct shdata
{
    int x;
};

void childf(int shared_memory, int index)
{
    // connect shared memory
    struct shdata* shm = (struct shdata*)shmat(shared_memory, NULL, 0);
    if(shm == (void*)-1)
    {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    // initialize x as 0
    if(index == 0)
    {
        shm->x = 0;
    }
    
    // increment x
    shm->x++;
    
    //show x
    printf("Proces %d: x = %d\n", index, shm->x);
    
    // disconnect shared memory
    if(shmdt(shm) == -1)
    {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    // end child process
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    // create shared memory
    int shared_memory = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 4096, 0600 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
    if(shared_memory == -1)
    {
        perror("shmget");
        return 1;
    }
    
    // create child processes
    for (int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++)
    {
        int pid = fork();
        if(pid == -1)
        {
            perror("fork");
            return 5;
        }
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            childf(shared_memory, i);
        }
    }
    
    // wait for child processes
    for(int i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++)
    {
        int wait_res = wait(NULL);
        if(wait_res < 0)
        {
            perror("wait");
            return 6;
        }
    }
    
    // delete shared memory
    int delete_memory = shmctl(shared_memory, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    if(delete_memory == -1)
    {
        perror("shmctl");
        return 4;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

There what I gets:

`Proces 0: x = 1 Proces 1: x = 2 Proces 2: x = 3 wait: Interrupted system call Program ended with exit code: 6`

But from time to time I dont receive this error. So what is the problem?

I expected:

`Proces 0: x = 1 Proces 1: x = 2 Proces 2: x = 3 Program ended with exit code: 0`

Comment: What `ERRNO` is set when `wait()` fails?

Comment: @Dash From the perror output, it's apparent that the errno is EINTR. It means that the wait was interrupted by a signal. This particular program doesn't seem to be interested in changing behavior based on signals, so you probably want to go back and wait again. [What is interrupted system call?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509375/what-is-interrupted-system-call)

Comment: Duh, don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

An otherwise benign signal can always interrupt `wait` (and other blocking system calls). If you are not interested in signals, just go back to waiting.

Instead of this

```
wait_res = wait(NULL);
```

use this:

```
while ((wait_res = wait(NULL)) == -1) {  
  if (errno != EINTR) break;
}
```